Property of record of random variables
Let $X_1, X_2, . . .$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed continuous random variables (following a uniform distribution in its support).
For $n ≥ 2$, $X_{R(n)}$ is said to be a record value of the sequence if $X_{R(n)} < \min(X_1, X_2, . . . , X_{R(n-1)})$ and the corresponding ${R(n)}$ is said to be a record.
Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \text{ln } R(n)}{n} = 1$$ with probability 1.
I am stuck at showing this equality. I think I need to define the $R(k)$ as an indicator function and then use strong law of large numbers. Please help.

I'm not sure I underestand the definition. Could you give an example? And what is $R(1)$?

I believe $R(1)=1$. If we have ${X_i}={.4, .62, .3, .1, .9, .31,…}$ then $R(2)=3$ and $R(3)=4$. These are the time indices when a new min is created.

I observe that for any continuous distribution, the probability a record is created at step $k$ is $1/k$.

@leonbloy, the definition following your comment is correct.

This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978388/counting-permutations-with-k-maximums

Using indicators are a good idea. Let us define $I_n$ to be the indicator of the event that $X_n$ is a record. The key is to first show the following lemma.
Lemma 1: The family $\{I_n\}$ is independent and
$$\Pr(I_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}.$$
This is a result known as the Dwass-Renyi lemma; the result you are after was itself first proven by Renyi, as far as I know.1 You should try proving the lemma yourself. A hint is that it is sufficient to consider permutations of a sequence of distinct values (why?), and calculate how likely it is for a given permutation to have some subset of positions be records. You can find a proof of the lemma in this question, for example.
Now, let $N(n) = I_1+\cdots+I_n$ denote the number of records up to the $n$th position. We can prove the following (weak) law of large numbers.
Lemma 2: We have $N(n)/\log n \rightarrow 1$ in probability.
Proof: From Chebyshev's inequality, we get
$$\Pr\left(\frac{|N(n)-H_n|}{\log n} \ge\varepsilon\right) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2\log^2 n}\mathrm{Var}(N(n)) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2\log^2 n}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right) \sim \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2\log n},$$
where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th Harmonic number. The result follows from the fact that $H_n/\log n \rightarrow 1$. $\square$
To finish, notice that
$$\Pr\left(R(n) \le m\right) = \Pr\left(N(m) \ge n\right).$$
Therefore we have
$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\left|\frac{\log R(n)}{n}-1\right| \ge \varepsilon\right) &= \Pr\left(\frac{\log R(n)}{n} \le 1-\varepsilon\right) + \Pr\left(\frac{\log R(n)}{n} \ge 1+\varepsilon\right)\\
&\le \Pr\left(N(m) \ge \frac{\log m}{1-\varepsilon}\right) + \Pr\left(N(m) \le \frac{\log m}{1+\varepsilon}\right)\\
&\le \Pr\left(\left|\frac{N(m)}{\log m} - 1\right| \ge \varepsilon\right),
\end{align}$$
where the last quantity vanishes as $m \rightarrow \infty$ due to Lemma 2. Note that in going from line 1 to 2 above, we write $m = e^{(1\pm \varepsilon)n}$ in each of the two terms (there's some finicking with floors and ceilings if you want to be fully precise; I've done it quite loosely). It follows that $\log R(n)/n \rightarrow 1$ in probability.
1Rényi, Alfréd, Théorie des éléments saillants d’une suite d’observations, Colloq. Comb. Methods Probab. Theor., Aarhus 1962, 104-115 (1962). ZBL0139.35303.
